# Как реализовать переподключение к БД

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных, pymysql

Я пишу простейший API для генерации капчи на Python 3.8. Ключи доступа у меня хронятсься в MySql на удаленном сервере (хостинге), а программа у меня запущена на локалке. Однако после долгого бездействия подключение к БД теряется, так как на сервере установлен timeout. По началу я думал просто увеличить его, но понимаю что это не выход, так как хочу что бы программа работала 24/7. Вот мой класс базы данных:

```py
class DataBase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.core = API_Core()
        self.connection = pymysql.connect(
            host=config.host,
            user=config.name,
            password=config.passwd,
            db=config.name,
            charset="utf8",
            cursorclass=DictCursor
        )

        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        timeout = 2147482
        self.cursor.execute(query=f"""SET SESSION wait_timeout := {timeout};""")
        self.connection.commit()
        log.debug("db inited")

    def add_key(self, access=10, expires=Access_levels.key_live_time)->str:
        key = self.core.generate_key()
        q = f"""INSERT INTO api_keys (access, api_key, expires) VALUES ({access}, '{key}', {int(time.time()) + expires})"""
        cur = self.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute(q)
        self.connection.commit()
        return key

    def __check_key_access(self, key: str) -> int:
        """Get access level for key"""
        q = f"""SELECT access FROM api_keys WHERE api_key='{key}'"""
        cur = self.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute(q)
        return cur.fetchone()

    def do_some_action(self, key: str, action: str):
        pass  # TODO
        acc = self.__check_key_access(key=key)["access"]

        if acc >= eval(f"Access_levels.{action}"):
            if action == "get_captcha":
                return True
                # TODO Time limit
            if action == "get_unlim_captcha":
                return True
            if action == "add_new_user":
                key = self.add_key()
                return key
            if action == "del_user":
                pass # TODO
            if action == "get_user_data":
                pass # TODO
```

Соответственно я сформулировал несколько вопросов:
Нужно ли отключаться от БД на время бездействия? И как это реализовать? Как сделать так что бы программа не вылетала с ошибкой, если после долгого бездействия программа пытается отправить запрос к БД? Если можно оставлять соединение открытым и на безопасность/быстродействие/ ресурсы это никак не влияет, то как сделать так что бы сервер не разрывал подключение? Просто не удалять курсоры? Или как?

Comment: почему бы не создавать подключение при обращении и закрывать сразу?

Comment: Потому что если обращения идут часто то мы будем постоянно подключаться / отключаться

Comment: Хотя наверное можно и так делтаь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно Вам стоит рассмотреть пул подключений к базе. Подобная реализация поддерживает пул соединений с базой и каждый раз при работе выдает готовое соединение, после чего возвращает его в пул. Кол-во соединений задаете вы. При этом при работе с другими БД (Oracle, PostgreSQL) возможно задать максимальное число соединений (сколько одновременно может быть открыто) и кол-во открытых на старте.

```
import mysql
from contextlib import contextmanager

class MSPool:
    def __init__(self):
        dbconfig = {
                 "database": "test",
                 "user":     "joe"
           }

        conn_pool = mysql.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name = "mypool",
                                                      pool_size = 3,
                                                      **dbconfig)
        if self.conn_pool:
            print("Connection pool created successfully")

    @contextmanager
    def connect(self):
        con = self.conn_pool.get_connection()
        try:
            yield con
            con.commit()
        finally:
            con.close()


pool = MSPool()

with pool.connect() as conn:
    #работа с подключением
```

Answer (score 0):

Либо выставить длительное ожидание в MySql

```
SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=....;
```

Желательно при работе с базой всегда проверяйте активность подключения.

Comment: Так у меня при инициализации класса ровно тоже самое делается `        timeout = 2147482
        self.cursor.execute(query=f"""SET SESSION wait_timeout := {timeout};""")
  `

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно создать методы.
Первый будет отвечать за подключение к базе, и хранить объект pymysql.connect в self.connection:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.connection = None
...

def mysql_conn(self):
    try:
        self.connection = pymysql.connect(
            host=config.host,
            user=config.name,
            password=config.passwd,
            db=config.name,
            charset="utf8",
            cursorclass=DictCursor
         )
    except pymysql.Error as e:
        print('MySQL Error: ' + e.args[1])
```

Второй, за проверку соединения.
Перед запросом проверять подключение, если соединения нет вызывать метод mysql_conn:

```
def mysql_check_conn(self):
    if not self.connection.open:
        self.mysql_conn()
```

Если постоянно идут запросы, то наверно стоит держать соединение открытым.